# AngularJS bootstrap collapsed init

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-init

I have the following html:

```
    <div class="pull-right text-success m-t-sm">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-init="isCollapsed = false" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Se kompetencer"><i class="fa {{isCollapsed == true ? 'fa-arrow-down': 'fa-arrow-up';}}" ng-click=""></i></button>
</div>

  <div collapse="isCollapsed" class="panel-body collapse" style="height: 0px;">
        <h4>Kompetencer</h4>

    </div>
```

As you can see from this code i `ng-init` the `isCollapsed` variable to false.

However when i run my page I get the following view:

[image]

As you  can see all of the boxes are visible? Can anyone tell me what might be going on here?

Note - I am not overwriting a variable or anything.

Maybe it has something to do with lazy load here is my config.router

```
    .state('app.competence', {
    url: '/Competence',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/app_competence.html',
    data: {
        authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.lb, USER_ROLES.superadmin, USER_ROLES.subadmin]
    },

    resolve: {
        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad',
            function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load(['ngGrid']).then(
                    function () {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load(['js/controllers/competence/CompetenceController.js','js/controllers/competence/CompetenceUserController.js', 'js/controllers/competence/CompetenceTableController.js', 'js/controllers/headerController.js']);
                    }
                );
            }]
    }
})
```

Html scope:

```
    <tab ng-controller="CompetenceUserController as cuCtrl">
    <tab-heading>
        <i class="icon-users text-md text-muted wrapper-sm"></i>Brugere
    </tab-heading>
    <div class="wrapper-md">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="panel no-body">
                    <div class="panel-heading wrapper b-b b-light">
                        <input class="form-control" ng-model="search.$" placeholder="Søg">
                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="search.competence" ng-options="comp.name "></select>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search:strict">
                            <div class="media">
                                <span class="pull-left thumb-sm"><img
                                        src="{{user.image_path || 'img/AdamProfil.png'}}" alt="..."
                                        class="img-circle"></span>

                                <div class="pull-right text-success m-t-sm">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-init="init(false)"
                                            ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                            data-placement="top" title=""
                                            data-original-title="Se kompetencer"><i
                                            class="fa {{isCollapsed == true ? 'fa-arrow-down': 'fa-arrow-up';}}"
                                            ng-click=""></i></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <div><a href="">{{user.profile.firstname +' '+user.profile.lastname ||
                                        user.username}}</a></div>
                                    <small class="text-muted">{{user.title.name}}</small>
                                </div>
                                <div collapse="isCollapsed" class="panel-body collapse"
                                     style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                    <h4 class="h4">Kompetencer</h4>

                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table table-striped b-t b-light">
                                            <thead>
                                                <th>Kompetence Navn</th>
                                                <th>Niveau</th>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr ng-repeat="comp in user.user_has_competences">
                                                    <td>{{comp.competence.name}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{comp.competence_level_id}}</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</tab>
```

My controller:

```
    app.controller('CompetenceUserController', ['$http', '$scope', '$sessionStorage','competenceService', '$log', 'Session', 'api', function ($http, $scope, $sessionStorage, $log, Session, api, competenceService) {
    $scope.init = function(value) {
        $scope.isCollapsed = value;
    };
    $scope.competences = [];
    competenceService.getRawList().then(function(response)
    {
        $scope.competences = response;
    });
    $scope.users = [];
    $http.get(api.getUrl('userCompetence', null)).success(function (response) {
        $scope.users = response;
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because you are initialising `isCollapsed` to `false` rather than `true`.

Comment: Hang on, you are setting `isCollapsed = false`. Are you expecting the controls to be visible (not collapsed) or not visible (collapsed)?

Comment: init should be not visible

Comment: then just change your `ng-init` to `isCollapsed = true`, demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/CmJRifA3Gi1dAN9MvY0n?p=preview

Comment: that did the trick can you please update your answer so it matches? :D

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning value to isCollapsed  to false which is not defined previously.`ng-init="isCollapsed = false"`

I prefer in this case to call a function and assign the value to variable.

```
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-init="init(false)" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Se kompetencer"><i class="fa {{isCollapsed == true ? 'fa-arrow-down': 'fa-arrow-up';}}" ng-click=""></i></button>
```

In controller

```
 $scope.init = function(value) {
    $scope.isCollapsed = value;
  }
```

You can alsoe directly assign

```
$scope.isCollapsed = false;
```

in controller.

Comment: Hey Squiroid this did not work. Could it be because i am lazy loading? ive added my routing config to my question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with the lazy loading, but rather that the `isCollapsed` isn't available in the scope you're referring it.

You can ensure it's available by wrapping it in an object (and maybe even declare your `ng-init` somewhere more up level).

Comment: let me post my scope and controller

Comment: i have posted my controller and html scope in my question

Comment: Okay. It's not a scope issue. I don't know that `collapse` attribute, is it a custom (angular) directive that should collapse that element if the expression is `true`?

Comment: Duh! I've should have known that _ui-bootstrap_ directive. Sorry -- in need of caffeine. Different approach: open dev tools in your favourite browser highlite the element with the `collapse` attribute and type in the console: `angular.element($0).scope().isCollapsed`. Check if the variable is updated when you toggle the button.

Comment: Also note there's an empty `ng-click` on the `<i>` element within the button.